# Sorting almost sorted array in $O(n)$ time

Tags: algorithms, sorting

What is the best way to sort an array that has at least half of its elements in their final position? Is it possible to achieve $O(n)$ running time?

Comment: You really mean final *position*, i.e., $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1$ is *not* almost sorted?

Comment: Do you want specifically a non-parallel comparison sort?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : I meant 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,9,8.  1 to 7 is already sorted but the last part is not.

Comment: @Arthur : As long as it can achieve O(n) time.

Answer (score 7):

$O(n)$ is not possible as your initial position might be $\frac n2$ small items in correct order followed by $\frac n2$ items in random order. Sorting the latter takes $O(n\ln n)$.

Comment: This is still assuming it's a comparison sort that is not done in parallel. For instance, bucket sort might, depending on what you're sorting, be linear no matter what the initial state of the list is.

Comment: It's actually $\sqrt{n}$ random elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can get an improvement to linear time if only $\frac{n}{\log{n}}$ items are out of place.  First, pick out the misplaced items (they will occur in runs where the endpoints do not compare correctly with a neighbor), this takes linear time.  Then use binary search on the remaining correctly-sorted items to find the correct positions for each misplaced item, this takes $O(\log{n})$ time for each item, so the total time is $O(n)$.